# Axios delete is ignoring the second argument

Tags: javascript, axios

This is my `createAsyncThunk`

```
export const removePlayer = createAsyncThunk(
    'player/removePlayer',
    async (playerId: any, thunkAPI) => {
        try {
            await axios.delete(URL, playerId)
        } catch (error) {
            return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error)
        }
    }
)
```

And this is the function that dispatches the action

```
<Button variant='outlined' onClick={() => {
     dispatch(removePlayer(player._id))
}}><DeleteIcon /></Button>
```

I have used `createAsyncThunk` for other CRUD operations like Read, Create and Update and they all work just fine. Am I using `axios.delete` wrong? This is what I feel. As you can see, all I want to do is pass in the player ID, then delete it, simple as that. I used very similar logic for `axios.put`, `axios.get` and `axios.post` and they all work fine

**EDIT** I can solve this by adding a `id` parameter to the route like so

```
router.delete('/:id', deletePlayer)
```

But im just curious if there is another alternative, because with axios post get and put, I can do it without using any params

Comment: What would you think it should do with the second element? Typically, with delete requests the element's ID is part of the url

Comment: By _"second argument"_, do you mean `config`? [axios.delete(url[, config\])](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosdeleteurl-config)

Comment: Typical REST guidelines treat `DELETE` requests like `GET` in that they rarely contain a request body. Usually you send a request like `DELETE /resource-name/id`. Of course, this entirely depends on what your server expects and you aren't limited by convention

Comment: I have edited my original post with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But im just curious if there is another alternative

Typically `DELETE` requests do not have a request body though that doesn't mean you cannot use one.

From the client side, something like this...

```js
axios.delete("/url/for/delete", {
  data: { playerId }
});
```

will send an `application/json` request with body `{"playerId":"some-id-value"}`.

On the server side, with Express you would use this

```js
router.delete("/url/for/delete", async (req, res, next) => {
  const { playerId } = req.body;

  try {
    // do something with the ID...

    res.sendStatus(204);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err.toJSON());
  }
});
```

To handle JSON payloads you should have registered the appropriate middleware

```js
app.use(express.json());
```